# Trouble uploading code to ESP12 with CH340g

Tags: esp8266, ch340

I have a programming circuit for the esp12(see attached) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YI2mk.png)

I have produced a pcb using this circuit. Upon plugging the pcb into my pc via the micro usb, the pc immediately recognizes the device.

The problem comes when I hit the upload button in the Arduino IDE. I get the following error:

```
Arduino: 1.8.9 (Windows Store 1.8.21.0) (Windows 10), Board: "NodeMCU 0.9 (ESP-12 Module), 80 MHz, Flash, Disabled, 4M (no SPIFFS), v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"

Sketch uses 265572 bytes (25%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1044464 bytes.
Global variables use 26984 bytes (32%) of dynamic memory, leaving 54936 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.
C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\tools\esptool\2.5.0-3-20ed2b9/esptool.exe -vv -cd nodemcu -cb 115200 -cp COM3 -ca 0x00000 -cf C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_988997/WiFiScan.ino.bin 
esptool v0.4.13-1-gf80ae31 - (c) 2014 Ch. Klippel <ck@atelier-klippel.de>
    setting board to nodemcu
    setting baudrate from 115200 to 115200
    setting port from COM1 to COM3
    setting address from 0x00000000 to 0x00000000
    espcomm_upload_file
    espcomm_upload_mem
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
An error occurred while uploading the sketch
opening bootloader
resetting board
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    read 0, requested 1
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    read 0, requested 1
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    read 0, requested 1
resetting board
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    read 0, requested 1
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    read 0, requested 1
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    read 0, requested 1
resetting board
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    read 0, requested 1
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    read 0, requested 1
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    read 0, requested 1
warning: espcomm_sync failed
error: espcomm_open failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Where is the error in my design that is preventing the successful upload in the Arduino IDE.

Edit: So I changed the CH340G to a CH340C and removed the 12MHz Crystal and the two 22pf caps connected the the 12MHz. It works perfectly now. I uploaded the code even at 921600 baud.

I guess the issue might have been which crystal I used or maybe the caps. Didn't think it would matter as long as the crystal is 12MHz, but maybe there is something else to account for.

Anyway...the new design will include the CH340C instead of the CH340G, but to be honest I will probably redesign it to use the CP2102.

Thank you for the quick responses. I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Well, the schematic seems OK and correct - have you tried putting the ESP into programming mode manually (tie GPIO0 to ground)

Comment: iirc, nodemcu 0.9 was a little funky. i would try other board profiles, including the generic.

Comment: Jaramanda X I did try to manually boot the ESP into flashing mode. I desoldered the auto-reset/auto-program components and just hooked it up to a breadboard with some push buttons. No success until I replaced the CH340G with a CH340C and removed the 12MHz and both 22pf caps. Programmed perfectly on the first try after that. Thank you for the quick response. Now I am going to go get drunk

Comment: So, I guess that means there's a difference in functionality between the `CH340G` and `CH340C` such that the former doesn't work with the `nodemcu` style reset circuit